# Why Isn't New-ADuser Copying Group Memberships?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that allows people to create a new user from scratch or copying another user but for some reason it is not copying AD group memberships.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am getting the user information with this command which is working fine.

```
$userToCopy = Get-ADUser -identity $copyUsername -Properties Department, title, Company, MemberOf
```

Then I am asking questions to get updated info for the new user then creating the new use with this command and everything works but the group memberships do not copy over which I was expecting that using the $userToCopy as the -Instance would do.

```
New-ADUser -SamAccountName "$username" -Name "$fname $lname" -DisplayName "$fname $lname" -Surname "$lname" -GivenName "$fname" -userprincipalname "$fname.$lname@$domain" `
               -AccountPassword $secPassword -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True -Office "$empID" -MobilePhone "$mobilePhone" -OfficePhone "$officePhone" -Title "$jobTitle" -department "$department" `
                 -ProfilePath "" -Path "$OUDN" -Instance $userToCopy -Credential $UserCredential -Server "BOM.chris.domain" -Enabled $True -Company "Chris"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue makes sense and then again it doesn't. Since ADUC supports copying groups from another account, it would seem like the same feature would be available with `New-ADUser -Instance`. However, `New-ADUser` does not seem to support updating group membership with any of its parameters. I can only guess, but I imagine this is because `MemberOf` is a calculated property rather than a direct attribute defined by the schema. You could do the following though with one line of code after creating the user.

```
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $username -MemberOf $UserToCopy.MemberOf -Server "BOM.chris.domain"
```

The code above without `-Identity $username` could be piped into after the `New-ADUser` command provided you add the `-Passthru` switch to `New-ADUser`.

Comment: Trying to pipe it I get the error: ERROR: User could not be created, check command and try running again in powershell
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But setting it on its own line like this works perfect.

Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $username -MemberOf $UserToCopy.MemberOf -Server "BOM.chris.domain" -Credential $UserCredential